# Cocos2d: How can I dynamically change size of array of CCSprite objects?

Tags: arrays, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

For example: I made this array to keep all my CCSprites:

```
CCSprite *Enemy[20];
```

I figured it would be okay, since I would have no more than 20 enemies, but now I want to be able to increase the size of it, once it's filled with objects, to be 40.

Comment: Use NSMutableArray to hold sprites, differentiate sprite with tags...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *mySprites = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


// array is mutable so you can add to it
[mySprites addObject: newSprite];

// objective c syntax has improved, you can now access elements with the following syntax
CCSprite *mySprite = mySprites[0];
```